# Is it possible to draw graphs on a given image using NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx

Is it possible to draw graphs on a given image (instead of on an empty figure) by using the python package NetworkX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this but it requires matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import networkx as nx
G = nx.cycle_graph(2)
pos =   {0:[0,0], 1:[ 300,  300]}
plt.figure(1)
img=mpimg.imread('/home/stinkbug.png')
plt.imshow(img)
nx.draw(G,pos)
plt.savefig('/home/test.png')
```

I used the stink bug on this [page](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/image_tutorial.html).

Using networkx by itself might be a little tricky.  Perhaps you could set the image you want as a node (say node 0) and then position the node at origin (0,0).  Finally, orient the other nodes from your graph on top of them.  I haven't tried it myself but its an idea that popped into my head.